# GmailApp.SendEmail() sometimes sends two emails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps

~20% of the time, my Google app script sends a duplicate email, seemingly randomly. I have tried switching the MailApp.sendEmail() to GmailApp.sendemail(), and adding in some sleep lines in case the code was somehow running again before it changed the sheet. I have only one on-change trigger running the script. Perhaps it's related to how many devices my gmail is logged in on? I'm very new at this, so I could just be missing something obvious.

Script:

```
function SortResponse() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;

  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var lasteq = values[Alast-1][2];
  var lastloc = values[Alast-1][3];
  var sentbox = values [Alast-1][31];
  var questions = 24;
  Utilities.sleep(4000);
    for (var i = 5; i <= questions; ++i) {
      var g = sheet.getRange(Alast,i).getValue();
      if (g != 'Good' && g != 'N/A' && g !== "") {           
        sheet.getRange(2,i).setValue(values[0][i-1]);
       }
    }
  // Send Alert Email.
  if (sentbox != "sent") {
    var comments = values[Alast-1][25];
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName").getRange("AJ2:AJ20");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
    var msgCell = sheet.getRange('AD1').getValues();
    var message = 'Equipment: '+lasteq+'\n at location: '+lastloc+'\n has been noted to need maintenance on: \n \n' +msgCell+'\n'+comments+' \n';
    var subject = 'Vehicle Inspection Maintenance Email Notification';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(Alast,32).setValue("sent");
    Utilities.sleep(4000);
    sheet.getRange("B2:Z2").clearContent();
  }
  Utilities.sleep(4000);
  sheet.getRange("B2:Z2").clearContent();
}
```

Triggers:
[Triggers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jdw7.png)

Duplicate Emails:
[Duplicate Emails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpIFS.png)

Spreadsheet Image:
[Spreadsheet Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSxPP.png)

Thanks for looking, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what Alast is because Avals is a 2 d array and I'm not sure what filter will do with that. Also how about this `var Avals = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();`

Comment: Thank you very much for the input. I just tried that for Avals instead, and the script seems to work the same, but still sent two emails.

Comment: I would need to see your spreadsheet to help you because I can't figure out what your doing from your code.

Comment: I've edited the post to include an image of the spreadsheet.

Comment: Column A is timestamp, B-D are basic info(name,item, location), E-Y are either "good", N/A", or "Needs Repair/Maintenance", and AF is the 'Sentbox' to signify that a row has been emailed and should not be emailed again. Rows 3 and greater are a query of a google forms response sheet that include rows where a maintenance response is submitted.

Comment: A likely reason is your incorporation of `sleep()` - so while the script is still running, it might be triggered a second time through a second onChange event. Since from the moment you retrieve `sentbox`s  value until the moment you set the value to `sent` 4000ms pass -  a second script triggered during this timespan will still find `sentbox != "sent"`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completed sure about this.  But without access to a spreadsheet with data I'm not interested in creating all of the data to test it.

```
function SortResponse() { 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SheetName");
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = range.getValues();
  var lv=values.length-1;
  var lasteq = values[lv][2];//Equipment
  var lastloc = values[lv][3];
  var sentbox = values[lv][31];
  var qA=sheet.getRange(lv+1,5,1,20).getValues();
  var aVrg=sheet.getRange(2,5,1,20);
  var aV=aVrg.getValues();
  for (var i=0;i<qA.length;i++) {
    if(qA[0][i]!='Good' && qA[0][i]!='N/A' && qA[0][i]!="") {           
      aV[0][i]=qA[0][i];
    }
  }
  aVrg.setValues(aV);
  if (sentbox != "sent") {
    var comments = values[lv][25];
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("SheetName").getRange("AJ2:AJ20");//Dont know where this is
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();
    var msgCell = sheet.getRange('AD1').getValue();
    var message=Utilities.formatString('Equipment: %s\nat location: %s\nhas been noted to need maintenance on:\n\n %s\n%s \n', lasteq,lastloc,msgCell,comments);
    var subject = 'Vehicle Inspection Maintenance Email Notification';
    GmailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    sheet.getRange(lv+1,32).setValue("sent");
  }
  sheet.getRange("B2:Z2").clearContent();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for writing that, it looks much cleaner. I guess there is no easy explanation why it was sending duplicate emails, but I'll try this and see if it stops it. I put the sleep lines in after it was already double emailing just to see if it would help, but it sounds like it would be smart to only have one at the very start of the script.